# Downloading file over HTTPS using Qt behind authenticating proxy

Tags: qt, https, download

I am trying to download a file, publicly available over an HTTPS URL, using Qt 4.8. I am behind a corporate authenticating proxy (over which I have no control).

I am using `QNetworkAccessManager`, as shown below:

```cpp
bool FileDownloader::download(const QString& fileUrl, const QString& fileName)
{
    QString outputFileName = fileName.isEmpty() ? fileNameFromUrl(fileUrl) : fileName;

    _file.setFileName(outputFileName);
    _file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    QUrl url(fileUrl);

    QNetworkReply* pReply = _networkAccessManager.get(QNetworkRequest(url));
    pReply->ignoreSslErrors();

    connect(pReply, SIGNAL(finished()), _pEventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(pReply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));
    connect(pReply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(const QList<QSslError>&)), this, SLOT(onSslErrors(const QList<QSslError>&)));
    connect(pReply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(onError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));

    _pEventLoop->exec();

    return true;
}
```

As soon as I call `QNetworkAccessManager::get()`, and receive a `QNetworkReply` object, I connect to its `sslErrors` signal as mentioned in the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#sslErrors%20docs). Following the same docs, I'm also calling `ignoreSslErrors()` in the slot connected to that signal:

```cpp
void FileDownloader::onSslErrors(const QList<QSslError>& sslErrors)
{
    QNetworkReply* pReply = (QNetworkReply*)(sender());
    pReply->ignoreSslErrors(sslErrors);
}
```

However, I never receive an `sslErrors` signal, I always get an `error` signal, which I'm handling in the `onError` slot, and which always says:

> SSL handshake failed

I'm calling the download functionality thus:

```cpp
FileDownloader fileDownloader;
fileDownloader.setProxy("http://username:password@proxyserver:8080");
fileDownloader.download(
        "https://679cc07dd5c2e4623d32-c8530501a6bee9a6c1860bbdab5cb6f1.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/9807/05377d04583309a88e808df5a1758e4e.png",
        "f:\\temp\\test.png"
```

I do not want to use other libraries like `libcurl` because I don't want to introduce dependencies.

So how can I download the file over HTTPS using Qt?

Comment: You might try a [QSslSocket](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2007/03/26/ssl-with-5-lines-of-code/). Do your proxy settings work in your application when you try to download a file over HTTP?

Comment: @m.s. Yes, the proxy settings work; the application can successfully download a file over HTTP. I'll try using QSslSocket. Thanks!

Comment: @m.s. So that example you pointed me to didn't quite work for me. For starters, I tried to get the home page of the Rackspace CDN server that I am using and QSslSocket simply refused to connect. Perhaps it is unable to authenticate  with the proxy that I am using?

Comment: can you use the proxy in your webbrowser and connect to a SSL site?

Comment: some more things to try: 1) do not use one string containing host, user and password but use the respective setter functions of QNetworkProxy; 2) do not specify the user and pass but connect to the onProxyAuthenticationRequired() signal, then set user/pass in the corresponding slot